# Rounding issues with decimal

Tags: c#, .net, decimal, rounding

I'm using the decimal data type throughout my project in the belief that it would give me the most accurate results. However, I've come across a situation where rounding errors are creeping in and it appears I'd be better off using doubles.

I have this calculation:

```
decimal tempDecimal = 15M / 78M;
decimal resultDecimal = tempDecimal * 13M;
```

Here resultDecimal is 2.4999999999999999 when the correct answer for 13*15/78 is 2.5. It seems this is because tempDecimal (the result of 15/78) is a recurring decimal value.

I am subsequently rounding this result to zero decimal places (away from zero) which I was expecting to be 3 in this case but actually becomes 2.

If I use doubles instead:

```
double tempDouble = 15D / 78D;
double resultDouble = tempDouble * 13D;
```

Then I get 2.5 in resultDouble which is the answer I'm looking for.

From this example it feels like I'm better of using doubles or floats even though they are lower precision. I'm assuming I manage to get the incorrect result of 2.4999999999999999 simply because a decimal can store a result to that number of decimal places whereas the double rounds it off.

Should I use doubles instead?

EDIT: This calculation is being used in financial software to decide how many contracts are allocated to different portfolios so deciding between 2 or 3 is important. I am more concerned with the correct calculation than with speed.

Comment: It's as likely that you can find another situation where the decimal result is correct and the double result wrong.

Comment: If you're doing scientific or engineering calculations rather than financial calculations, you should generally be using `double` anyway, since it's hundreds of times faster than `decimal`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I could see that I might not get a result to so many decimal places with a double but given that I'm ultimately rounding to zero decimal places am I really like to get the wrong final result with a double?

Answer (score 1):

Strange thing is, if you write it all on one line it results in 2.5.

If precision is cruical (financial calculations) you should definately use decimal. You can print a rounded decimal using `Math.Round(myDecimalValue, signesAfterDecimalPoint)` or `String.Format("{0:0.00}", myDecimalValue)`, but make the calculations with the exact number. Otherwise double will be just fine.

Comment: If I try 15M / 78M * 13M it still gives me 2.4999999999999999. I know 13M * 15M / 78M gives the right answer but that's because the multiplication happens first. I'd rather not do the multiplication first in my example because there's the potential for the number to overflow.

Comment: @DavidJohnston: the advice here is the best anyone can give. Computers aren't magic; any numeric type will have specific limitations on the numbers that type is capable of representing. Just because you happened across a ratio that `decimal` can't represent exactly doesn't mean that `decimal` is the wrong type for your scenario. You say you are dealing with financial calculations, so `decimal` is definitely the right choice here. But you still need to be cognizant of the possibility of imprecision. Even `decimal` can't represent `1/3` exactly.

Comment: @DavidJohnston: It's up to you to format numbers when displayed to users, to address the difference between how human beings deal with numbers and how computers deal with them. Let the computer deal with the number in its way, and use appropriate formatting codes to round the computer's number to something useful for a human, when you display that number to a human.